# Log in on a site with python

Tags: python, get, python-requests

I'm quite new to this topic. That's the code that I found, but it doesn't work:

```
s = requests.Session()
payload = {'name': 'admin', 'pass': el[0:5]}
r = s.get("http://shadowctf.cloudapp.net/web200", data=payload)
print(r.text)
```

That's the form from the site:

```
<form action="send.php" method="GET">
        <h1>Log in!</h1>
        <br><input type="text" name="login" /></br>
        <br><input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" /></br>
        <br><input type="submit" value="Log me in!" /></br>
</form>
```

The code above just returns me:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>JustSomePage</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <style></style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <form action="send.php" method="GET">
        <h1>Log in!</h1>
        <br><input type="text" name="login" /></br>
        <br><input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" /></br>
        <br><input type="submit" value="Log me in!" /></br>
    </form>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't you forgotten to add "send.php" to your url? Probably instead of web200.

Comment: I've fixed it, now it works, but how to understand, when the login is successful? UPD: no problem, my fault